# Get value from dynamic ui:inputSelect in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have selectbox in my Lightning component. It displays data from "leadFieldOptions" and set default value from "selectedValue".

```
<ui:inputSelect multiple="false" value="{! selectedValue }">
    <aura:iteration items="{! leadFieldOptions }" var="option">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{! option.value }" label="{! option.label }"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

After I change value in selectbox "selectedValue" still has previous value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing Value Provider.

i.e) 
**Value providers used to access data and encapsulate related values together, similar to how an object encapsulates properties and methods.**

The value providers for a component are `v (view) and c (controller)`. [Learn Usage of Value Provider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm)

```
<ui:inputSelect multiple="false" value="{!v.selectedValue }">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.leadFieldOptions }" var="option">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{! option.value }" label="{! option.label }"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

Comment: How would you get the value if the inpoutselected was generated inside a loop? so you cant assign value?